# Is there any way to capture an event inside a function using an id or class of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to capture an `onclick` event of a button using its id inside a function and then trying to `console.log` the value! but i think that because the event capture code is inside a function its not detecting when the event fires! is there any way around it! thank you !

```js
window.onload = xyz;

function xyz() {
click();
 
  }
 function click() {
    var x = document.querySelector("#btn");
    x.addEventListener("click", myfunction);
    console.log(x);}

function myfunction() {
  document.querySelector(".example").style.backgroundColor = "red";
  return 1;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="example">A heading with class="example"</h2>

<p>Click the button to add a background color to the first element in the document with class="example".</p>

<button id="btn">Try it</button>
```

Comment: It looks like your code would work, just call click after the elements exist. Though I'm not sure what exactly is "_the value_" you want to log to.

Comment: myfunction is not equal to myFunction - change that and it should work.  Also you never call the click function to bind the event

Comment: First of all, you never call your `click` function. Secondly JS is case sensetive so `myfunction` and `myFunction` are not the same.

Comment: @Smollet777 i have edited my question check even after changing name and calling the function using window.location its not triggering

Comment: @pete i have edited my question check even after changing name and calling the function using window.location its not triggering

Comment: you still don't call the click function - you just wrpped it and called the outer function - nothing calls the click function that binds it

Comment: It should be window.onload = click. Unless you add click() to the end of the xyz function, but that serves no purpose at all.

Comment: @shilly i have defined it in the way you explained but stiill doesnt work

Comment: Just remove the click wrapper function, and your [code works](https://jsfiddle.net/7kr1sn9p/). "_the value_" is still a problem, what is the value "_the_" refers? If it's `1` in the actual event listener, it is not going to work. Event listener functions are called by browser's event queue, and they are returning to the bitspace. You can't get a return value from a callback like this.

Comment: @pete i think you are correct thats what i wanted to know from this post

Comment: @Teemu thats what i wanted to know if the click event will trigger if its wrapped inside a function, rest of the code i just wrote it out of the blue serves no purpose

Comment: @everyone the code is working now lol

Comment: @everyone thank you for the time in correcting me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use the jQuery **on** like this.

```
$("#btn").on( "click", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
  document.querySelector(".example").style.backgroundColor = "red";
  return 1;
}
```

This would work.

Also I didn't check if it is the only problem in your example but it seems that you have a mistake in the name of the function called  myfunction => myFunction

```
x.addEventListener("click", myFunction);
```

Comment: that would work but is there any way to make it work by defining the addeventlistener inside a custom function? thank you for your time in answering it tho

Comment: @FaizalMohaideenKadersha an inline click handler would be ok for you? Something like <button id="btn" onclick ="myFunction()">Try it</button>

Comment: @FaizalMohaideenKadersha you should remove the jquery tag if you do not want jquery answers

Answer (score 1):

You can turn the click function into an IIFE:

```js
(function click() {
  var x = document.querySelector("#btn");
  x.addEventListener("click", myFunction);
  console.log(x);
})()

function myFunction() {
  document.querySelector(".example").style.backgroundColor = "red";
  return 1;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="example">A heading with class="example"</h2>

<p>Click the button to add a background color to the first element in the document with class="example".</p>

<button id="btn">Try it</button>
```

Also make sure the capitalization matches when calling the functions

Comment: @dimitry is there any way around it to make it happen without turning the function to Immediately Invoked Function Expression